# Akka not showing log output

Tags: scala, logging, akka

I am on Scala 2.10.2 and Akka 2.2 and has the following test

```
import org.junit._
import Assert._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import net.liftweb.json._
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.event.Logging

class AppTest {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("annotator-common")
  import system.dispatcher // execution context for futures below

  val log = Logging(system, getClass)

@Test
  def testHttp() = {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

    val respBody = AsyncHttpProvider.getResponseBodyAsJValue("http://some-json-api-url")

    respBody onComplete {
      case Success(contents) => {
        val x = contents \\ "self"
        log.info(x.toString)
      }
      case Failure(error) => log.error(error.toString)
    }
    Thread.sleep(2000) //adding this allows the future to complete before the test
  }
}
```

`AsynHttProvider.getResponseBodyAsJValue` returns `Future[JValue]`. Regardless of whether the http calls fails or succeed, I am not getting any console output. Anyone knows why?

**EDIT**
Actually what I didn't mention is that if I add a call to the non future based http API, it will print out the log output of both calls, so I don't think it's the log settings. For that matter, I am seeing the same issue with `println`.

I am able to resolve the issue by adding this, see updated code above

```
Thread.sleep(2000)
```

Comment: Obvious first question: have you have looked at logging options [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/scala/logging.html)? Chances are, you might have turned logging off.

Answer (score 3):

My guess: The test is terminated before the future has been executed. I.e. you return void but don't wait for the future to be completed.

Comment: I think you are right, so what's the best way to fix that? I tried using Await.result without success.

Comment: You need to await something which gets completed after your logging is done. Currently you register an asynchronous callback that gets run at some later time, a pure side effect (onComplete returns Unit). You should look at andThen for example.

Comment: Ah ok but what if I don't need to do anything else after my logging is done? Is there a best practice for handling something like this?